# Shader: extrusion of 2D texture

Tags: shader, rendering, volumes

### The Objective

Given a 2D texture applied to a cube I want to render an extrusion in its depth without doing any iterative operation, so classic parallax is not viable way of doing this.

Now I will contemplate a single face, the generation of the sides can wait

the desired effect:
[image: the desired effect]

---

### Collecting constants:

In UE4 I found a "Interior Cubemap" preset node that through the camera vector insets the face by a depth factor:

`1/tangentSpaceCameraVector * (-1,1,1) * (u, v, depth)`

passing all vectors through min():
[image: passing all vectors through min()]

this lets me generate an accurate representation of the backfaces of the cube and gets the last position of the extrusion on the backplane without artefacts

the front and back plane:
[image: the front and back plane]

What I could also generate through the view vector is a cylinder with a value on its circumference and another for its depth, this way I could have a numbered representation of the intersecting with the planes.

mockup of the cylinder in perspective:
[image: mockup of the cylinder in perspective]

---

### Looking for a solution

I could only gather some ideas on how to solve this issue, some of those would break a classic render pipeline.

The most logical way I could imagine would be to use as index of an 1D array the represented values of the cylinder (that would work as a raycast) and set them when drawing the texture in UV space to the highest value found.
In other words when rendering the image in uv space the value writes in the array to the index of the ray in the same pixel.
Afterwards when interpelling the pixels of the cylinder itself I would know if they lay on a ray that has hit the texture and decide whether to render them or not.
I could also store as value the hit depth and use it to limit the ray length to that maximum value in order to not let it draw after the shape bounds.
This, anyways, wouldn't work in a normal pipeline.

The other solutions I contemplated always get into iterations and are not what I'm looking for.

I may be wrong and this is impossible to solve, I'm just staring at the quantity of constants I have access to and can't find a viable solution, I actually know the position of both planes, their representation and can't interpret the pixels in-between those because I would need a depth information I can't interpel without iterations.

Another way of looking at this issue would be to think this as a volume rendering with an UVW where W is 1 but stretched by the cube's depth

Hope to get some useful insights, I am learning a lot about shaders through this exercise